# .end() function not entered when using async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, supertest

I am using supertest with async to test some websites.
When I execute the test with mocha, the end function is not entered.
I added some logging to the end function but it isn't printed.
When I remove the async.each, the end function **is** entered because I see the logging. Any idea what seems to be wrong?
Is supertest not compatible with async?

Here is my code:

```
describe('Era', function() {
it('Does era run?', function(done) {
    async.each(config.url.era, function(url) {
        console.log('Opening connection to ' + url);
        request(url).get('/rest/status').expect(200).end(function(err, res) {
            console.log(err);
            if(err) return done(err);
            console.log('Time to assert some stuff');
            assert.equal(res.text.indexOf('up') > -1, 'Node ' + url + ' failed with status ' + res.statusCode);
        });
    });
    done();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

async.each() is expecting a callback for each iteration to continue on.  In addition, an optional callback at the end of async.each() can be used to call done().  Here is the revised code:

```
describe('Era', function() {
    it('Does era run?', function(done) {
        async.each(config.url.era, function(url, eachCb) {
            console.log('Opening connection to ' + url);
            request(url).get('/rest/status').expect(200).end(function(err, res) {
                console.log(err);
                if (err) return eachCb(err);  // terminate the loop
                console.log('Time to assert some stuff');
                assert.equal(res.text.indexOf('up') > -1, 'Node ' + url + ' failed with status ' + res.statusCode);
                eachCb(null);  // continue with the next iteration
            });
        }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            done();
            // the above 2 statements can be simplify for just
            // done(err);  // err is an error or null
        });
    });
});
```

or above code can be simplified for just this:

```
describe('Era', function() {
    it('Does era run?', function(done) {
        async.each(config.url.era, function(url, eachCb) {
            console.log('Opening connection to ' + url);
            request(url).get('/rest/status').expect(200).end(function(err, res) {
                console.log(err);
                if (err) return eachCb(err); // terminate the loop
                console.log('Time to assert some stuff');
                assert.equal(res.text.indexOf('up') > -1, 'Node ' + url + ' failed with status ' + res.statusCode);
                eachCb(null);  // continue with the next iteration
            });
        }, done);  // async.each() will call done() with err or null as argument
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was confused with the callbacks. This works!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call the callback `done`:

```
it('Does era run?', function(done) {
    async.each(config.url.era, function(url) {
        console.log('Opening connection to ' + url);
        request(url).get('/rest/status').expect(200).end(function(err, res) {
            console.log(err);
            if(err) return done(err);
            console.log('Time to assert some stuff');
            assert.equal(res.text.indexOf('up') > -1, 'Node ' + url + ' failed with status ' + res.statusCode);
        });
        // call at end of each async call
        done();
   });
});
```